# what uid means in python, is it a keyword or just a variable?

Tags: python, networking, throttling

I saw following example on a website

```
 import throttle

def some_fun(uid):
    if not throttle.check(key=uid, rate=30, size=10):
        raise ThrottleError()
```

but I am not getting what uid means here?

Comment: see the answer below, pls accept it helps to understand .

Answer (score 1):

`uid` is not keyword or  variable its called `Parameter` which are specified after the function name, inside the parentheses. You can add as many parameters as you want, just separate them with a comma.

## Just for the illustration purpose

```
$ cat nfunc.py
#!/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
def my_function( headers):
      print(headers + " Gusain")

my_function("Jungi")
my_function("Arjun")
my_function("Kirpal")

$ ./nfunc.py
Jungi Gusain
Arjun Gusain
Kirpal Gusain
```

Please check [Here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/functions-python-tutorial?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=1t1&utm_creative=278443377083&utm_targetid=aud-299261629574:dsa-473406571355&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9061662&gclid=Cj0KCQjw3ebdBRC1ARIsAD8U0V6HSjZwQ8b0JTaQ4qGdWJdPy0fbb83fKbxw8kgYLvAGKGiEFxUN9eAaArY8EALw_wcB) about the python `functions`.